# OpenCV : Reversing the negative areas of an image

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

i'm using OpenCV 3.4.6 in a c++/Objective C project and given an image with negative rectangular areas, like this one:

[image: Image With Negative Rectangles]

I should detect those negative areas, reverse them and finally get the original image.

I tried to use **findContours**, enhancing the **contrast** of the original image or adding a **threshold** but the rectangles are not detected.

Here one of the test i've tried:

```
Mat contrasted = [self enhanceContrastTo: matOriginal];

Mat thresholded;
threshold(contrasted, thresholded, 125, 241, THRESH_BINARY);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours( thresholded, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_RETR_TREE );

/* contrast method */
+(Mat)enhanceContrastTo:(Mat)image {

 cv::Mat lab_image;
 cv::cvtColor(image, lab_image, CV_BGR2Lab);

 // Extract the L channel
 std::vector<cv::Mat> lab_planes(3);
 cv::split(lab_image, lab_planes);  // now we have the L image in lab_planes[0]

 // apply the CLAHE algorithm to the L channel
 cv::Ptr<cv::CLAHE> clahe = cv::createCLAHE();

 // clahe->setClipLimit(4);
 clahe->setClipLimit(3);

 cv::Mat dst;
 clahe->apply(lab_planes[0], dst);

 // Merge the the color planes back into an Lab image
 dst.copyTo(lab_planes[0]);
 cv::merge(lab_planes, lab_image);

 // convert back to RGB
 cv::Mat image_clahe;
 cv::cvtColor(lab_image, image_clahe, CV_Lab2BGR);

 return image_clahe;
}
```

The rectangles are clearly visible to the naked eye, I hope that opencv can also identify them but I don't know how.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to know the solution too. Hope someone can help!

Comment: My initial thought is to use a discrete fourier transform: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html. I've never actually had a use case to utilize this function but I imagine those certain spots should be noticeable in the frequency domain. Let me know if you try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I followed the code shown in the link [https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d8/d01/tutorial_discrete_fourier_transform.html), but I get a result that I can't interpret, maybe I'm doing something wrong, this is my code: [Code](https://gist.github.com/albertowao/d265df30c65ca5f4cc422c23d3522574), and this is the result: [Result](https://imgur.com/a/aSrrdVH)

Answer (score 1):

This particular question isn't too complicated but even minor variants can get complex. I can advise you on a couple of simple ideas that should suffice to solve the problem.

1) Instead of contour you can check whether neighboring points are close to reverse - this should filter out most irrelevant edges. But just checking for near-reverse is not sufficient as monotone grey area (127) fits the criteria too. Require also minimal threshold difference.

2) Since rectangles are parallel to axes - you can simply go along each row and column and count the number of pixels that are potentially edges of the reversed rectangles. It is better not to just count the number - but to check whether you have continuous large sequences of such pixels and record where exactly these segments are.

3) Use the found segments (or just indexes of rows and columns) of reversed edge-pixels to make candidates for reversed rectangles and then make final verifications.

This is but an algo draft - it will surely require refining. I am not sure why you wanted to use the contour function, tho.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought that findCountours could work because the negative areas are very detached from the rest of the image so I believed that the rectangles could be identified without fail in one go. Now I'm following your proposal but I'm not getting good results (I'm probably doing something wrong). It would be nice if there was a function that understands that those areas are different from the rest

Comment: @NucciDev There is nothing that can identify reversed blocks. Only edges are somewhat distinct from the rest. Perhaps some smart AI can tell the difference. Were you able to identify rows/columns via the suggestion? If not try to figure out why.